nginx reverse proxy port inaccessible
The setup is very simple. A docker container is running and listens to port 2283. It is accessible from the brower of the server with http://localhost:2283
I have the following nginx configuration:
    server {
        listen 88;
        server_name _;

    location /{
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2283;
        }
}

The docker service can then be accssed on the same server via: http://localhost:88
But on a different device of the same network, I cannot connect to (timeout) http://<server internal ip>:88 while http://<server internal ip>:2283 is accessible.
The firewall ufw is inactive and I can confirm that nginx is listening to port 88:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:88           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::88                :::*                    LISTEN     

This is my first time using it as reverse proxy. I'm so confused now. Any help is appreciated.

I'm 99.99% sure it's firewall.

@AlexeyTen Yes! Problem solved now. I didn't mention I was using WSL. So there's also a layer of often ignored "firewall" between windows and linux. A port proxy configuration is needed.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan

Try explicitly binding NGINX to the server's internal IP address like so (i've also added IPv6 listen directive there just to be on the safe side):
server {
    listen <server_internal_ip>:88;
    listen [::]:88;  # For IPv6 support
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2283;
    }
}

In addition to the above i would check SELinux module (if applicable) to see if it is restricting NGINX from making outgoing connections by running:
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
Also check your iptables.
